# Matlab: loading a .mat file, why is it a struct? can I just have the stored vars loaded into memory?

Tags: matlab, matlab-load

Relevant code:

```
function result = loadStructFromFile(fileName, environmentName) 
    result = load(fileName, environmentName);


bigMatrix = loadStructFromFile('values.mat','bigMatrix');
```

But when I look in the workspace, it shows 'bigMatrix' as a 1x1 struct. When I click on the struct, however, it is the actual data (in this case a a 998x294 matrix).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the documentation of [LOAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/load.html) indicates, if you call it with an output argument, the result is returned in a struct. If you do not call it with an output argument, the variables are created in the local workspace with the name as which they were saved.

For your function `loadStructFromFile`, if the saved variable name can have different names (I assume `environmentName`), you can return the variable by writing

```
function result = loadStructFromFile(fileName, environmentName) 
    tmp = load(fileName, environmentName);
    result = tmp.(environmentName);
```

Comment: what an absolutely disgusting api design (of Matlab's `load()`)... Thanks for the explanation though!

Answer (score 3):

Even when you just specify a single variable name, [LOAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/load.html) will still output it in a structure. In your case, one option you have is to use the function [STRUCT2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/struct2cell.html) to convert the output from [LOAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/load.html) into a cell array, then return this result using a [variable output argument list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/varargout.html):

```
function varargout = loadStructFromFile(fileName,environmentName)
  varargout = struct2cell(load(fileName,environmentName));
end
```

Using [VARARGOUT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/varargout.html) has the added benefit that, if `environmentName` matches multiple variables in the .MAT file, you can return them all from your function. For example, if your .MAT file has three variable `N1`, `N2`, and `N3`, and `environmentName` is `N*`, you can get them all by calling your functions with multiple outputs:

```
[N1,N2,N3] = loadStructFromFile('values.mat','N*');
```

Answer (score 2):

It is an old post, but if it can be useful for some people:

When you load a structure, and you want to assign directly the subfields in the output structure, you can use `structfun` and the following command:

```
bigMatrixOUT = structfun(@(x) x,load('values.mat','bigMatrix'))
```

`bigMatrixOUT`  will contain directly the fields of `bigMatrix`, and not `bigMatrixOUT.bigMatrix`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try accessing the known field using dot notation so it all happens in one line of code.

```
bigMatrix = load('values.mat','bigMatrix').bigMatrix;
```

or

```
bigMatrix = load('values.mat','bigMatrix').('bigMatrix');
```