# Undefined function or method 'mtimes' for input arguments of type 'struct'

Tags: matlab

I have an array of size 550x128. I save it in a .mat file and load it again to use it in another function.

```
save('c:\\coeffs2.mat', 'descr2');
des2=load('c:\\coeffs2.mat');
```

I use this value further as follows:

```
des2t = des2';                          
for i = 1 : size(des1,1)
dotprods = des1(i,:) * des2t;
```

where des1 is another array which I'm passing though normal function calling rather than using save and load. Using this I get the error as Undefined function or method 'mtimes' for input arguments of type 'struct'. Can someone please help me with the error?

Comment: Could you post more code? This is a bit too terse.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718417/matlab-loading-a-mat-file-why-is-it-a-struct-can-i-just-have-the-stored-vars

Answer (score 3):

When you use `des2=load('c:\\coeffs2.mat');` then it makes a struct `des2` with the variables from `'c:\\coeffs2.mat'` in it. Here is an example:

```
>> a=rand(3);
>> save b a
>> c=load('b')

c = 

    a: [3x3 double]

>> c.a

ans =

    0.8147    0.9134    0.2785
    0.9058    0.6324    0.5469
    0.1270    0.0975    0.9575
```

If you don't want to have to use the struct, instead just use `load('c:\\coeffs2.mat');`. Then there will be a variable `descr2` that you can use. Here is an example using the file I just made:

```
>> clear all
>> load('b')
>> whos
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  a         3x3                72  double              

>> a

a =

    0.8147    0.9134    0.2785
    0.9058    0.6324    0.5469
    0.1270    0.0975    0.9575
```